# Are canonical projections of $\Bbb{R}^n$ Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

If $(X, \mathcal{A})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B})$ are measurable spaces and a function $f : (X, \mathcal{A}) \hookrightarrow (Y, \mathcal{B})$ . We say that $f$ is *$(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B})$-measurable* if $\forall E \in \mathcal{B} : f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{A}$ .

Let $\mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}^n)$ denote the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb{R}^n$

In order to use this to solve an excercise, I want to know if the canonical projections of $\Bbb{R}^n$

$$\forall k \in [1,n] \cap \Bbb{Z}, \pi_k : \Bbb{R}^n \hookrightarrow \Bbb{R}, (x_j)_{j=1}^n \mapsto x_k$$

are $(\mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}^n), \mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}))$-measurable. I have tried to think about it but I am not getting anywhere.

In my book the only there is a characterization about real valued measurable functions which says that $f: X \hookrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is measurable iff $\forall t \in \Bbb{R} : f^{-1}(-\infty, t) $ is measurable on $X$.

The problem is that I don't know if in this characterization the $\sigma$-algebra considered on the codomine $\Bbb{R}$ is the Borel or the Lebesgue and the book does not say anything about that.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For a fixed $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f^{-1}(-\infty,t) = \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times (-\infty,t)$? Now its a matter of knowing how the Lebesgue measure is defined for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @user57 My book's definition is $$\lambda^* : P(\Bbb{R^n}) \hookrightarrow [0, \infty], A \mapsto \inf \{ \sum_{k \in \Bbb{N}} vol(R_k) : \{R_k\}_{k\in \Bbb{N}} \subset R(A) \}$$ where for every $A \subseteq \Bbb{R^n}$ we denote by $R(A)$ as the set of countable infinite families of $n$-dimensional intervals (called rectangles) whose unions covers $A$. The problem is, I thought previously what you said, but what about the question I wrote in the next-to-last paragraph?

Comment: The final characterization you wrote down is equivalent to your earlier characterization if the co-domain $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, since that is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $(-\infty, t)$. A somewhat boring example showing that this is not the same as when $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra: Just let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $f$ be the identity map.

Comment: Regardless, the projection maps are $(\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n), \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable. The point here is that for any Borel $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $\pi_k^{-1}(X)$ is still Borel. And if $X$ is also null, then so is $\pi_k^{-1}(X)$. So as any Lebesgue measurable set is the union of a Borel set and a subset of a Borel null set, its inverse image is the union of a Borel set and a subset of a Borel null set as well, so Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @DavidGao This is perfect, thanks!